# Add dropdown to only a few cells in a handsontable

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I'm trying at add a table where in the first column I have a dropdown set. But i want the dropdown content to be different for group of cells in that column. For ex: i want the first 4 rows of Column1 with dropdown of some data and next 5 rows in that column with dropdown of different data. My concern is how to initialize the data to it since we just specify data in the column method while initailizing. Is it possible with the current version of handsontable i.e 0.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you specify data in the `column` method, you can do the same with the `cells` method which works exactly like the columns one but takes row and column indices